# Can I use Client (Browser) IP as Proxy for cURL?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I've a very basic tool (for educational purposes) where someone can input string, the tool uses cURL (data sent using AJAX) to bring response data from 3rd party API.

So, my question is, is there any way I can use the user's IP (I'm already getting the user IP using `https://api.ipify.org` for other personalization purpose in the tool) as a Proxy IP in cURL.

If yes, which port do I have to use (port `80`)?

**Edit:** Here's what I exactly want to do:

- Use the client's IP in the PHP cURL query by using a `CURLOPT_PROXY` field in the `curl_setopt`. Is this possible?

**(I'm already sending the Client's IP to my PHP page (using AJAX) for some other part of server code)**

Comment: The answer is "no you can't", unless you open mile wide security holes on your own page to allow cross site ajax requests. You do not want to do that.

Comment: @arkascha I'm using PHP for making cURL request. And, my plan is to send this client IP using AJAX to my own PHP page, and do the cURL from their. So, in this case, is it possible?

Comment: Your _server side_ obviously cannot somehow use the _client side_'s IP address. That is why I claimed above that the answer is "no". Reason simply is the network topology.

Comment: @arkascha I'm still not sure if I'm clear in explaining it or not, but let me try it once again.

I'm already sending the client IP (grabbed using api.ipify.org) to my PHP page for some purposes. So, my question is, will I be able to use this IP in the PHP cURL adding the `CURLOPT_PROXY` field for the API query (just like how we use some third party Proxy servers in cURL)?

Comment: No, the knowledge of the client IP (which you _always_ know in php, with or without that service) does not help. The client is no proxy, but a client. You cannot use a client as a proxy. That is like trying to use a hammer to glue paper. Just because you _specify_ some option does not mean that the word changes accordingly. If that IP does not operate a proxy _and_ grants you access, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Actually it might be possible to setup some primitive proxy on the client side (javascript based) by using web sockets... but you cannot use that by means of `cURL` but have to implement your own http client library. And I don't see any advantage over making a cross site ajax request in the first place. This would only add an enormous complexity _if_ that is possible at all.

Comment: @arkascha Okay. Thanks for explaining it in detail.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not making a cross site ajax request. It's to my own PHP page on the same domain.

Comment: Those are different things. _if_ you succeeded in getting the client site to contact that 3rd parts service for your proxy request, then that _would_ obviously be a cross site request, since you are not that 3rd party...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131804/discussion-between-paras-shah-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No It's that simple answer.. A major security threat. Would you like if some one uses your IP to DDOS CIA.